# startActivity method makes error

Tags: android

I'm trying to write simple App that calls some certain number.
I wrote in the manifest uses permission for Call_Phone and still my startActivity marked red.
can someone know how to solve this problem?

```
package com.example.programmer.gate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Gate extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button b;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gate);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);


        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123");
                **startActivity(callIntent);**
            }
        });
    }

   }
```

Comment: what error does it make? is it syntactical or run time?

Answer (score 0):

Check permission

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:+123"));
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
}
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your application's targetSdkVersion greater than 22, then it requires run time permission. May be that makes the error in your application. So please check your gradle file for confirmation. I think this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

### Your code is ok

Just you need to add user permission in AndroidManifest.xml

### Like this

```
     <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```